# Firebase Analytics - export userId

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

Do you know how exactly export userId field via BigQuery works in Firebase Analytics?

In https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6205850?hl=en I found information that:

- "The userId field, which can be set to a stable, non-personally identifiable ID to represent a unique user"
- "Although the session data is available via the Core Reporting API, the userId field is not available as a dimension in reports and can not be exported from Analytics."

On the other hand, I found several articles which talk about connecting users from Analytics (via BigQuery) to users from other databases/services (like https://www.periscopix.co.uk/blog/google-analytics-user-id-in-bigquery/). However for me they shouldn't be as trustful as google docs. Did you have some experiences with work with that?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do if you really want to get what FB uses as userID, you can try and grab it as a property from the tracker object and pass it back as a custom dimension.

Generally, however, this ID may be different from what GA does, so people just generate their own user ids for authenticated users and send them as custom dimensions to be able to bind the hits/sessions/users not only across devices, but also to their CRM, backend DBs or even low-level event logs.